# Number of bytes in memory taken by the below structure is

Tags: c, structure

Number of bytes in memory taken by the below structure is

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    struct test
    {
        int k;
        char* c;
    };
```

Comment: If I wanted to know I'd just `printf("%d\n", (int)sizeof(struct test))`.

Comment: I am not good at the c programming..this question have following answers could tell me which one correct?A:5B:4C:8D:6

Comment: @SangamChoudhari answer E: it depends.

Comment: Yes it depends and that's why you should use sizeof(struct test) to find out instead of guessing.

Comment: i recommend you read about struct padding and memory packing, because the bytes in the memory allocated for this struct are not  continuously located.

Answer (score 3):

Depends on machine architecture and its memory alignment. Generally, on 32-bit machine it will give `8` bytes.
And on 64-bit machine it will give 16-bytes. Its because `4` padding bits will be added after `int k;`.

Try to find out it with

```
printf("%zu\n", sizeof(struct test));
```

Comment: That depends on the alignment requirements of the machine.  I checked it on my 64 bit DS9k and it told me 4096 bytes.

Comment: @user464502; `4096` bytes??

Comment: The DS9k has strange alignment requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Call the below line in your `main()` you will get answer depends on the machine architecture:

```
printf("%zu",sizeof(test));
```

Comment: `u` would require a cast to `unsigned int` not `int`; just use `zu` to avoid to cast `sizeof`.

Answer (score 1):

The `int` actually is a legacy, that was historically of the same length as (any*). In modern systems with a register size 64bit you will have the sizeof(int)=32. But the pointer is always of the size of the processors register size. So you have 32bit + 64bit on a 64bit system or 2*8bit on a 8bit system. But the size of a structure also depends on memory alignment.

The way to find out how long such a structure is, is given by the C operator `sizeof`. Here: `sizeof(struct test)`.

To define the length of the `int` in our days you should use the types from `#include <stdint.h>`.

Comment: Not true, on 64-bit machines `int` is typically still 32 bits, while pointers are 64 bits.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned before you can use the sizeof to check it but basically the size of a struct it is the sum of the its components (in your case a sizeof(int) + sizeof(char*)).